# return the body of a POST request from a Cypress command

Tags: javascript, cypress

Given a Cypress command that makes a POST request

```
Cypress.Commands.add('createTask', () => {
  cy.route('POST', '/events/*/tasks').as('postTask')

  // clicking this button triggers the POST request above
  cy.get('[data-cy="add-task"]').click()

  cy.wait('@postTask')
  cy.get('@postTask').then(xhr => {
    expect(xhr.status).to.eq(200)
  })
})
```

Assume that the response body returns a JSON object such as

```
{taskId: 99}
```

When this command is invoked from a test with

```
it('create a new task on an existing event', () => {
  cy.createTask()
})
```

How can I access the JSON response of the POST request? I'm also curious to know if it's possible to access the actual value of the `*` placeholder in the URL?

Comment: try xhr.response.body

Comment: console xhr value, you will get an idea of how to get request and response

Comment: use cy.wrap to return